# is there any way to give --quick option while using mysqlsh util.loadDump()?

Tags: mysql-shell

is there any way to give --quick option to avoid the problem?

[problem]

oom killer activates while loading large tables using 'mysqlsh util.loadDump()'.

On mysqldump, using quick option let's you write data into instance without buffering, avoid memory problems.

However, mysqlsh util.loadDump() dosen't seem to provide similar options.

Am I missing something? or should there be any work around please share...